# ember data 2.3.x how to get the metadata with jsonapi

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

> DEBUG: -------------------------------
>   DEBUG: Ember             : 2.3.0
>   DEBUG: Ember Data        : 2.3.1
>   DEBUG: jQuery            : 2.1.4
>   DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth : 1.0.0
>   DEBUG: -------------------------------

My server side send the data with `jsonapi` like this:

```
  data: [{  
   ... ,  
   1: {  
     attributes: {  
       id: '123',  
       ... ,   
       meta: {  
         price_total: {  
           datasets: ... ,  
           labels: ...  
         }  
       }  
     }  
   },  
   ...  
 }]
```

I check the document https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/models/handling-metadata/ , check to get the metadata in my template.

```
 {{#each model as |fittingItem index|}}  
   ...  
   {{fittingItem.meta}}  
   ...  
 {{/each}}
```

I could not get meta.

I found some issues https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2905 , https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3419 . They also can not solve my problem.

Maybe there is any better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metadata (as it relates to JSONAPI) is currently only supported in Ember-Data for collections of data, and should be defined as a top level document key.

http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-top-level

It appears what you are trying to achieve is some level of meta data for each individual record, which is possible if you define a custom meta attribute on your model definition.

```
fooMeta: DS.attr()
```

Using an empty `attr()` allows ember-data to just let any value from json to "pass through" to your model without any transformation.. (though you could also define a custom transform to tweak your meta values a bit...)

also there is an addon [ember-data-model-fragments](https://github.com/lytics/ember-data-model-fragments) which, may be of some help defining arbitrary "chunks" of data within your models.

Comment: Maybe `DS.attr()` is best way to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35514055/how-to-access-top-level-meta-key-from-json-api-servers-200-response-when-callin) declares how to reopen DS.Model to parse metadata from calls stages by find/save/destroyRecord that manipulate single instance by their nature,

Comment: I have checked with Ember 2.3.0, Ember-data 2.3.0 and the answer is no, no meta property on the loaded models is available. `Ember.RSVP.hash({ languages: this.store.findAll("language") }).then((models) => { console.log(models.languages.get("meta")); // outputs undefined });`